# Logstash wont start when adding a match statement in a grok block

Tags: docker-compose, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I'm having difficulty with starting `Logstash`.

My `logstash.conf` looks like this:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
  }
}

filter {
 grok {
   patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
   match => { "message" => "%{WORD:event_type}\t%{NUMBER:server_time}\t%{NUMBER:market_time}\t%{WORD:instrument}\t%{C_NUMBER:last_price}\t%{C_NUMBER:trade_quantity}\t%{C_NUMBER:bid_price}\t%{C_NUMBER:bid_quantity}\t%{C_NUMBER:ask_price}\t%{C_NUMBER:ask_quantity}\t%{GREEDYDATA:flags}\t%{GREEDYDATA:additional_infos}"}
 }

 # ... and other stuff here...
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}"
  }
}
```

Logstash works fine if I comment the `match =>` line. But with it, it does not start, meaning nothing shows up when I run `netstat -na | grep 5044` in the container. It is simply not listening on 5044.

And when I try to run Logstash manually by `/opt/logstash/bin/logstash --path.data /tmp/logstash/data -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/filebeat-config.conf`, I get the following:

```
Sending Logstash's logs to /opt/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-08-27T09:35:25,883][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/tmp/logstash/data/queue"}
[2018-08-27T09:35:25,887][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/tmp/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2018-08-27T09:35:26,177][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-08-27T09:35:26,213][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"5abcdba2-475f-46a9-b192-a343ca15ce89", :path=>"/tmp/logstash/data/uuid"}
[2018-08-27T09:35:26,727][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.3.2"}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,016][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,316][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,325][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,467][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,510][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,513][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,533][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,549][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,565][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,689][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Error registering plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main", :plugin=>"#<LogStash::FilterDelegator:0x68bd7527 @metric_events_out=org.jruby.proxy.org.logstash.instrument.metrics.counter.LongCounter$Proxy2 -  name: out value:0, @metric_events_in=org.jruby.proxy.org.logstash.instrument.metrics.counter.LongCounter$Proxy2 -  name: in value:0, @metric_events_time=org.jruby.proxy.org.logstash.instrument.metrics.counter.LongCounter$Proxy2 -  name: duration_in_millis value:0, @id=\"e473071da674c7efab2a8ee71c9e682afff58b8a4725d076964bc668f3b2c724\", @klass=LogStash::Filters::Grok, @metric_events=#<LogStash::Instrument::NamespacedMetric:0x5867faed @metric=#<LogStash::Instrument::Metric:0x61ef1454 @collector=#<LogStash::Instrument::Collector:0x51306706 @agent=nil, @metric_store=#<LogStash::Instrument::MetricStore:0x5227344a @store=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fb4 entries=2 default_proc=nil>, @structured_lookup_mutex=#<Mutex:0x7efeb9ea>, @fast_lookup=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fb8 entries=75 default_proc=nil>>>>, @namespace_name=[:stats, :pipelines, :main, :plugins, :filters, :e473071da674c7efab2a8ee71c9e682afff58b8a4725d076964bc668f3b2c724, :events]>, @filter=<LogStash::Filters::Grok patterns_dir=>[\"./patterns\"], match=>{\"message\"=>\"%{WORD:event_type}\\\\t%{NUMBER:server_time}\\\\t%{NUMBER:market_time}\\\\t%{WORD:instrument}\\\\t%{C_NUMBER:last_price}\\\\t%{C_NUMBER:trade_quantity}\\\\t%{C_NUMBER:bid_price}\\\\t%{C_NUMBER:bid_quantity}\\\\t%{C_NUMBER:ask_price}\\\\t%{C_NUMBER:ask_quantity}\\\\t%{GREEDYDATA:flags}\\\\t%{GREEDYDATA:additional_infos}\"}, id=>\"e473071da674c7efab2a8ee71c9e682afff58b8a4725d076964bc668f3b2c724\", enable_metric=>true, periodic_flush=>false, patterns_files_glob=>\"*\", break_on_match=>true, named_captures_only=>true, keep_empty_captures=>false, tag_on_failure=>[\"_grokparsefailure\"], timeout_millis=>30000, tag_on_timeout=>\"_groktimeout\">>", :error=>"pattern %{C_NUMBER:last_price} not defined", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x20b6525c run>"}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,699][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<Grok::PatternError: pattern %{C_NUMBER:last_price} not defined>, :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/jls-grok-0.11.5/lib/grok-pure.rb:123:in `block in compile'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1292:in `loop'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/jls-grok-0.11.5/lib/grok-pure.rb:93:in `compile'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.0.3/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:281:in `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.0.3/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:275:in `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1343:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-grok-4.0.3/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:270:in `register'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:340:in `register_plugin'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:351:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:351:in `register_plugins'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:729:in `maybe_setup_out_plugins'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:361:in `start_workers'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:288:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:248:in `block in start'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x20b6525c run>"}
[2018-08-27T09:35:29,724][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
```

Also, next to my `logstash.conf`, I have the directory `patterns` including a file containing the following:

```
USERNAME [a-zA-Z0-9._-]+
USER %{USERNAME}
INT (?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+))
BASE10NUM (?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))
NUMBER (?:%{BASE10NUM})
C_NUMBER (?:[+-]?(?:[(0-9)|(*,@,.)]+))
C_NUMBER2 (?:[+-]?(?:[(0-9)|(*,@,.)|null]+))
BASE16NUM (?<![0-9A-Fa-f])(?:[+-]?(?:0x)?(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]+))
BASE16FLOAT \b(?<![0-9A-Fa-f.])(?:[+-]?(?:0x)?(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]+(?:\.[0-9A-Fa-f]*)?)|(?:\.[0-9A-Fa-f]+)))\b
POSINT \b(?:[1-9][0-9]*)\b
NONNEGINT \b(?:[0-9]+)\b
WORD \b\w+\b
NOTSPACE \S+
SPACE \s*
DATA .*?
GREEDYDATA .*
QUOTEDSTRING (?>(?<!\\)(?>"(?>\\.|[^\\"]+)+"|""|(?>'(?>\\.|[^\\']+)+')|''|(?>(?>\\.|[^\\]+)+`)|``))
UUID [A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}
MAC (?:%{CISCOMAC}|%{WINDOWSMAC}|%{COMMONMAC})
CISCOMAC (?:(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}\.){2}[A-Fa-f0-9]{4})
WINDOWSMAC (?:(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}-){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})
COMMONMAC (?:(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}:){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})
MONTH \b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b
MONTHNUM (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])
MONTHDAY (?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])
DAY (?:Mon(?:day)?|Tue(?:sday)?|Wed(?:nesday)?|Thu(?:rsday)?|Fri(?:day)?|Sat(?:urday)?|Sun(?:day)?)
YEAR (?>\d\d){1,2}
HOUR (?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])
MINUTE (?:[0-5][0-9])
SECOND (?:(?:[0-5][0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?)
TIME (?!<[0-9])%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}(?::%{SECOND})(?![0-9])
DATE_US %{MONTHNUM}[/-]%{MONTHDAY}[/-]%{YEAR}
DATE_EU %{MONTHDAY}[./-]%{MONTHNUM}[./-]%{YEAR}
ISO8601_TIMEZONE (?:Z|[+-]%{HOUR}(?::?%{MINUTE}))
ISO8601_SECOND (?:%{SECOND}|60)
TIMESTAMP_ISO8601 %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}?
TIMESTAMP_CUSTOM %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND}.?%{NUMBER})?%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}?
DATE %{DATE_US}|%{DATE_EU}
DATESTAMP %{DATE}[- ]%{TIME}
TZ (?:[PMCE][SD]T|UTC)
DATESTAMP_RFC822 %{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{YEAR} %{TIME} %{TZ}
DATESTAMP_OTHER %{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{TZ} %{YEAR}
```

**What is wrong with the `match =>` line?? 
I highly appreciate your help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing `patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]` to `patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns"]`.

The `match` line is referencing a `grok pattern` that `Logstash` didn't find because of the relative path to the patterns directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use a grok pattern, {C_NUMBER}, that Logstash doesn't know about. It doesn't appear to be a standard pattern bundled with Logstash. put NUMBER in that place, and restart logstash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm pretty sure the problem was with the relative path.